# How to get link of file to download with wget

Tags: c#, selenium, wget

For automation purposes, I need to download this excel file with a script on C#.

On the following link: https://live.euronext.com/products/etfs/list are the buttons for downloading the excel file, which I attached on the images bellow.

On the images is the way

[image]

[image]

But I cannot get the link. I tried with selenium, with click on this button. I tried also to find a link using console, but nothing worked. Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Install Fiddler - https://www.telerik.com/fiddler - it will capture & display the request.

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you for your suggestion. But it also cannot capture the link with telerik.

Comment: Without changing any of the options on the website the download link looks like this: https://live.euronext.com/pd/data/track/download?mics=XAMS%2CXBRU%2CXLIS%2CXPAR%2CXLDN%2CXMSM&display_datapoints=dp_track&display_filters=df_track

Comment: @Kaskorian This link doesn't download the excel sheet, instead it downloads an empty HyperText Markup Language file.

Comment: You asked for the link. The link is correct. But when clicking on the button a form is submitted. So you have to send a POST request and not a GET request. Also, you have to keep track of the data send with the POST request. You cannot just open the link.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I did for you what I mentioned in my last comment:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    public class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Post data
            string queryString = @"
                draw=92&
                columns[0][data]=0&
                columns[0][name]=&
                columns[0][searchable]=true&
                columns[0][orderable]=true&
                columns[0][search][value]=&
                columns[0][search][regex]=false&
                columns[1][data]=1&
                columns[1][name]=&
                columns[1][searchable]=true&
                columns[1][orderable]=false&
                columns[1][search][value]=&
                columns[1][search][regex]=false&
                columns[2][data]=2&
                columns[2][name]=&
                columns[2][searchable]=true&
                columns[2][orderable]=false&
                columns[2][search][value]=&
                columns[2][search][regex]=false&
                columns[3][data]=3&
                columns[3][name]=&
                columns[3][searchable]=true&
                columns[3][orderable]=false&
                columns[3][search][value]=&
                columns[3][search][regex]=false&
                columns[4][data]=4&
                columns[4][name]=&
                columns[4][searchable]=true&
                columns[4][orderable]=false&
                columns[4][search][value]=&
                columns[4][search][regex]=false&
                columns[5][data]=5&
                columns[5][name]=&
                columns[5][searchable]=true&
                columns[5][orderable]=false&
                columns[5][search][value]=&
                columns[5][search][regex]=false&
                columns[6][data]=6&
                columns[6][name]=&
                columns[6][searchable]=true&
                columns[6][orderable]=false&
                columns[6][search][value]=&
                columns[6][search][regex]=false&
                columns[7][data]=7&
                columns[7][name]=&
                columns[7][searchable]=true&
                columns[7][orderable]=false&
                columns[7][search][value]=&
                columns[7][search][regex]=false&
                order[0][column]=0&
                order[0][dir]=asc&
                start=0&
                length=20&
                search[value]=&
                search[regex]=false&
                args[initialLetter]=&
                args[fe_type]=excel&
                args[fe_layout]=ver& 
                args[fe_decimal_separator]=.&
                args[fe_date_format]=d/m/y&
                iDisplayLength=20&
                iDisplayStart=0&
                sSortDir_0=asc";

            // Because of the more readable version of the query string, there are a lot of new lines and tabs which have to be removed.
            string cleanedQueryString = queryString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
            cleanedQueryString = cleanedQueryString.Replace("\t", "");

            var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(cleanedQueryString);
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => values[k]));

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = client.PostAsync("https://live.euronext.com/pd/data/track/download?mics=XAMS%2CXBRU%2CXLIS%2CXPAR%2CXLDN%2CXMSM&display_datapoints=dp_track&display_filters=df_track", content).Result;
            var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\malo0\Downloads\Euronext_ETPs_2020-10-26.xls", responseString);
            Console.WriteLine("Done!!!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Query String:**
These are the 4 option you can set in the download popup

```
args[fe_type]=excel          // selection between xls, csv, txt
args[fe_layout]=ver          // layout horizontal/vertical
args[fe_decimal_separator]=. // decimal separator option
args[fe_date_format]=d/m/y   // date format option
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and solution! I only have one more problem, when I run this code. In the line "client.PostAsync("live.euronext.com/pd/data/track/…", content).Result;" it throws an exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: One or more errors occurred. Was it the same case by you?

Comment: Yes. That happens sometimes. For me, the error occurs when you send too many requests in a given time span. It seems like the host closes connections if he received too many requests from the same client. This error also occurs when you do it in the browser. Unfortunately, you cannot forcibly reproduce the error. Just try to wait for a given time span and resend the request. If you go into the browser and open the website, go to the development tool -> network and wait. You will see that every 30 seconds the websites send the request of my answer to update.